# "Failed to fetch" error message in Infura

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-http-client

Steps

1. Using "ipfs-http-client" npm library
2. setting up auth with projectId, privateKey from infura

```
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'

const privateKey = '...'
const projectId = '...'
const auth =
  'Basic ' + Buffer.from(projectId + ':' + privateKey).toString('base64')
const INFURA_URL = 'something.infura-ipfs.io'

const client = create({
  host: INFURA_URL,
  port: 5001,
  protocol: 'https',
  headers: {
    authorization: auth,
  },
  apiPath: '/ipfs/api/v0',
})
```

Calling ipfs client

```
const fileUrl = await client.add(image)
```

returns an error "Failed to fetch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use dedicated gateways to access IPFS content, not to upload content. Please follow this [link](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/how-to/manage-files) for more info.

Your solution will be to replace the sub-domain with which is
**something.infura-ipfs.io** to
**ipfs.infura.io** and hopefully it should work.

For details about Dedicated gateways, please follow [this](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/how-to/access-ipfs-content/dedicated-gateways) link.

Cheers.